# Mysql: Select records which are NOT assigned e.g. to a specific group

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table with members and assigned groups.

```
col1   | col2
-------|--------
user 1 | group 1
user 1 | group 2
user 1 | group 3
user 2 | group 2
user 2 | group 3
user 3 | group 1
user 4 | group 2
```

Now I want to select all user which are NOT in a specific group,
e.g. all users which are not in group 1
should give as result: user2 and user4

Comment: `select * from table_name where col1 not in ('val1','val2');`

Comment: OP wants to filter on col2, and seems to want distinct values from col1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM users_groups 
WHERE user_id NOT IN (
     SELECT user_id FROM users_groups
     WHERE group_id IN ('group 1')
 )
```

Comment: Is it working? I've tried it with my mysql sample table, but all the time, it keeps displaying all the three users

Comment: doesn't work for me either, it gives me additionally every user which is assigned to another group